# SQL / Spring data - how to get the complete row based on min value in column and distinct id

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a view that concentrates all data I need to show a list with establishment and the cheapest beer in this place. Sometimes I need filter the establishment and the price of the cheapest beer according with the label and packing of the beer, so, my view returns a lot of lines with almost the same result:

[image: Table]

The rows marked with red square is the ones I want show. To get the resultset as in the picture, I've used JpaSpecificationExecutor with some specifications, the final SQL is this:

```
SELECT
  visaoaplic0_.id_estabelecimento   ,
  visaoaplic0_.embalagem_id         ,
  visaoaplic0_.rotulo_id            ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_cidade          ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_embalagem       ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_estabelecimento ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_estado          ,
  visaoaplic0_.preco                ,
  visaoaplic0_.tipo_estabelecimento,
  visaoaplic0_.icone                ,
  visaoaplic0_.icone_content_type
FROM visao_app_aba_locais visaoaplic0_
WHERE upper(visaoaplic0_.nome_cidade) = 'MONTES CLAROS' AND     upper(visaoaplic0_.nome_estado) = 'MINAS GERAIS' AND
  (upper(visaoaplic0_.nome_estabelecimento) LIKE '%') AND
  (visaoaplic0_.tipo_estabelecimento IN (1006, 1053, 1148, 1008, 1009, 1007)) AND
  (visaoaplic0_.id_estabelecimento IS NOT NULL);
```

The problem now is that I have no idea how to get only the rows I need, neither using SQL or using criteria API.

**About the answers**

I will need use JPQL or Criteria API, if you know how to solve this only in SQL, please show a sentence independent of database vendor (perhaps in SQL:2011), so I can translate to JPQL or Criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

So It can be SQL or it can't be? Here are some SQL versions most are for sql server but a couple will work for whatever.

An option to simply move the rows to the top:

```
SELECT
  visaoaplic0_.id_estabelecimento   ,
  visaoaplic0_.embalagem_id         ,
  visaoaplic0_.rotulo_id            ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_cidade          ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_embalagem       ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_estabelecimento ,
  visaoaplic0_.nome_estado          ,
  visaoaplic0_.preco                ,
  visaoaplic0_.tipo_estabelecimento,
  visaoaplic0_.icone                ,
  visaoaplic0_.icone_content_type
  ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY visaoaplic0_.id_estabelecimento ORDER BY
    IIF(visaoaplic0_.preco IS NULL,1,0) ASC
    ,ISNULL(visaoaplic0_.preco,0) ASC
    )
FROM visao_app_aba_locais visaoaplic0_
WHERE upper(visaoaplic0_.nome_cidade) = 'MONTES CLAROS' AND     upper(visaoaplic0_.nome_estado) = 'MINAS GERAIS' AND
  (upper(visaoaplic0_.nome_estabelecimento) LIKE '%') AND
  (visaoaplic0_.tipo_estabelecimento IN (1006, 1053, 1148, 1008, 1009, 1007)) AND
  (visaoaplic0_.id_estabelecimento IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
    RowNum
;
```

Test Data for next queries

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Establishment VARCHAR(100), Price MONEY)
INSERT INTO @Table (Establishment, Price)
VALUES ('A',4.5),('B',5.5),('B',3.05),('C',6.75), ('D',NULL), ('C',NULL)
```

Windowed Function with Common Table Expression Dealing with Null better than simply if null present as first price?

```
;WITH cteQuery AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Establishment ORDER BY
          IIF(Price IS NULL, 1, 0) ASC
          ,ISNULL(Price,0) ASC)
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT
    Establishment
    ,Price
FROM
    cteQuery
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1
```

Other Options

```
----Windowed Function with Common Table Expression
;WITH cteQuery AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Establishment ORDER BY ISNULL(Price,0) ASC)
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT
    Establishment
    ,Price
FROM
    cteQuery
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1


--- Group By with Common Table Expression Method
;WITH cteMin AS (
    SELECT
       Establishment
       ,MinPrice = MIN(ISNULL(Price,0))
    FROM
       @Table
    GROUP BY
       Establishment
)

SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    cteMin m
    INNER JOIN @Table t
    ON m.Establishment = t.Establishment
    AND m.MinPrice = ISNULL(t.Price,0)



-----Group By with Sub Select Method
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    @Table t
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT
          Establishment
          ,MinPrice = MIN(ISNULL(Price,0))
       FROM
          @Table
       GROUP BY
          Establishment
    ) g
    ON t.Establishment = g.Establishment
    AND ISNULL(t.Price,0) = g.MinPrice
```

Comment: The answer can be in SQL, but I'll need transform it in JPQL or Criteria Query, this way, queries specific for a database won't help.